# What are the possible values for CreateParams.Style?

Tags: c#-4.0

So, I've been playing with trying to create an AppBar program I'm making.  Now, the program itself is actually quite simple but I had to borrow some code from a CodeProject project to make it an AppBar.

So, my code is the following:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct RECT
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct APPBARDATA
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public IntPtr hWnd;
        public int uCallbackMessage;
        public int uEdge;
        public RECT rc;
        public IntPtr lParam;
    }

    enum ABMsg : int
    {
        ABM_NEW = 0,
        ABM_REMOVE,
        ABM_QUERYPOS,
        ABM_SETPOS,
        ABM_GETSTATE,
        ABM_GETTASKBARPOS,
        ABM_ACTIVATE,
        ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAR,
        ABM_SETAUTOHIDEBAR,
        ABM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED,
        ABM_SETSTATE
    }
    enum ABNotify : int
    {
        ABN_STATECHANGE = 0,
        ABN_POSCHANGED,
        ABN_FULLSCREENAPP,
        ABN_WINDOWARRANGE
    }
    enum ABEdge : int
    {
        ABE_LEFT = 0,
        ABE_TOP,
        ABE_RIGHT,
        ABE_BOTTOM
    }

    private bool fBarRegistered = false;
    private int uCallBack;
    private int whereToPin;

    [DllImport("SHELL32", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    static extern uint SHAppBarMessage(int dwMessage, ref APPBARDATA pData);
    [DllImport("USER32")]
    static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int Index);
    [DllImport("User32.dll", ExactSpelling = true,
        CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool MoveWindow
        (IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, bool repaint);
    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string msg);

    private void RegisterBar()
    {
        APPBARDATA abd = new APPBARDATA();
        abd.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(abd);
        abd.hWnd = this.Handle;
        if (!fBarRegistered)
        {
            uCallBack = RegisterWindowMessage("AppBarMessage");
            abd.uCallbackMessage = uCallBack;

            uint ret = SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_NEW, ref abd);
            fBarRegistered = true;

            ABSetPos();
        }
        else
        {
            SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_REMOVE, ref abd);
            fBarRegistered = false;
        }
    }

    private void ABSetPos()
    {
        APPBARDATA abd = new APPBARDATA();
        abd.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(abd);
        abd.hWnd = this.Handle;
        abd.uEdge = whereToPin;

        if (abd.uEdge == (int)ABEdge.ABE_LEFT || abd.uEdge == (int)ABEdge.ABE_RIGHT)
        {
            abd.rc.top = 0;
            abd.rc.bottom = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height;
            if (abd.uEdge == (int)ABEdge.ABE_LEFT)
            {
                abd.rc.left = 0;
                abd.rc.right = Size.Width;
            }
            else
            {
                abd.rc.right = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width;
                abd.rc.left = abd.rc.right - Size.Width;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            abd.rc.left = 0;
            abd.rc.right = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width;
            if (abd.uEdge == (int)ABEdge.ABE_TOP)
            {
                abd.rc.top = 0;
                abd.rc.bottom = Size.Height;
            }
            else
            {
                abd.rc.bottom = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height;
                abd.rc.top = abd.rc.bottom - Size.Height;
            }
        }

        SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_QUERYPOS, ref abd);

        switch (abd.uEdge)
        {
            case (int)ABEdge.ABE_LEFT:
                abd.rc.right = abd.rc.left + Size.Width;
                break;
            case (int)ABEdge.ABE_RIGHT:
                abd.rc.left = abd.rc.right - Size.Width;
                break;
            case (int)ABEdge.ABE_TOP:
                abd.rc.bottom = abd.rc.top + 100;
                break;
            case (int)ABEdge.ABE_BOTTOM:
                abd.rc.top = abd.rc.bottom - Size.Height;
                break;
        }

        SHAppBarMessage((int)ABMsg.ABM_SETPOS, ref abd);
        MoveWindow(abd.hWnd, abd.rc.left, abd.rc.top,
                abd.rc.right - abd.rc.left, abd.rc.bottom - abd.rc.top, true);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == uCallBack)
        {
            switch (m.WParam.ToInt32())
            {
                case (int)ABNotify.ABN_POSCHANGED:
                    ABSetPos();
                    break;
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    protected override System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style &= (~0x00C00000); // WS_CAPTION
            cp.Style &= (~0x00800000); // WS_BORDER
            cp.ExStyle = 0x00000080 | 0x00000008; // WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST
            return cp;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        whereToPin = (int)ABEdge.ABE_LEFT;
        RegisterBar();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        whereToPin = (int)ABEdge.ABE_RIGHT;
        RegisterBar();
    }
}
```

My two questions are:
What are the possible values cp.Style and how do those values effect the display of the AppBar?  (The code to which I refer to is located in the System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams override)

I see they are values such as (~0x00C00000) but I have no idea how they work beyond those specific values and can't seem to find any enumeration of different values.

I'm a rather new, self teaching, programmer who does well by taking examples and molding them to my own uses.  Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you go...

- [Window Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632600.aspx)

As per the OP's original query, there's also:

- [Window Class Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729176%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)